# Find a value in a string and output it to a text file via a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to output a numeral value from a ffmpeg output and add it to a text file.

I'd like to run it as a single line from a batch file where I have all my variables set up already, but I'm not sure if it's even possible.

This is the output string, from where i want to copy the `average` value:

```
[Parsed_psnr_0 @ 0000000003763ec0] PSNR y:18.250891 u:33.358190 v:36.566447 average:19.962586 min:11.944585 max:41.255356
```

In this case `19.962586`, i got several 100 files to process and the number is always different.

Here is a weak attempt out of ignorance to do that:

```
powershell Get-Content -Path "'D:\work folder\test.txt'" | -match 'average:(.+?) min:' | Out-File -Path "D:\work folder\test_result.txt"
```

not working and neither did the 100 variations I tried, but I've included it as a rough idea of what I am trying.

Comment: You can pull the average value with pure batch file code as well.

Comment: the following is a working powershell solution that worked: powershell -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'C:\file.txt').Split(' ') | foreach { if ($_ -match 'average'){ $_ -replace """[^^.0-9]""" , '' | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\file_output.txt' -Append}}"

credit goes to Adrian C.

Comment: Then post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is a working powershell solution:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'C:\file.txt').Split(' ') | foreach { if ($_ -match 'average'){ $_ -replace """[^^.0-9]""" , '' | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\file_output.txt' -Append}}"
```

credit goes to Adrian C.

Answer (score 0):

Test string:

```
[Parsed_psnr_0 @ 0000000003763ec0] PSNR y:18.250891 u:33.358190 v:36.566447 average:19.962586 min:11.944585 max:41.255356
```

PowerShell solution (can toss into a `.cmd` file):

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content -Path 'D:\workfolder\test.txt') -match 'average:(.+?)' | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\workfolder\test_result.txt' -Append"
```

---

Update:

```
SET "PS=%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
%PS% -Command "gc 'D:\workfolder\test.txt'|%{If($_-match 'average:(.+?)'){$Matches[0]}}|Out-File -FilePath 'D:\workfolder\test_result.txt' -Append"
```

Comment: this will output "True". is it possible to pass the actual value (19.962586) to the output?

Comment: @secondplace Did you try? `Get-Content` should return an array and when `-match` is used, it will return the matches which then get piped to `Out-File`.  Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: the following version: PSVersion 5.1.14393.1914

Comment: i get the following error: Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible ways you can do this with a batch file.  There are other solutions as well. But either of these should work based on your example.

```
@echo off
REM Option 1
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims=:" %%G IN (test.txt) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1" %%H IN ("%%~G") DO set "average1=%%~H"
)
echo average1: %average1%

REM option 2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (test.txt) DO (
    set "line=%%~G"
    FOR /F "tokens=1" %%H IN ("!line:*average:=!") DO set average2=%%H
)
endlocal&set "average2=%average2%"
echo average2: %average2%

pause
```